# SQL Server ERROR Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, database

I have to truncate the table but getting error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Table".

Code:

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'

AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE abcDB.dbo.'+@Table) AT [Server]
END
```

Comment: What is the `AS` doing there?

Comment: @Martin Smith you are right now its solved by erasing the AS and write the query inside begin and end block

Comment: @Martin Smith thanks for your suggestions and time

Answer (score 2):

Declare the varaible After `AS` keyword.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE abcDB.dbo.'+@Table) AT [Server]
END
```

Comment: variables aren't block scoped in TSQL.

Comment: @ahmed abdelqader I voted it up but it's saying 15+ reputation can vote and I am new member. Sorry for that

Comment: the issue would be the variable name is added in a newline

Comment: @MartinSmith, you are correct , the issue is not related to begin and End, it is related with AS keyword, so my Answer is valid, and I edited it

Comment: @ahmed abdelqader vote me to increase my reputation so that I would eligible for voting..........

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Thanks a lot, now I am eligibled to accept any question

Answer (score 1):

Check if u have any constraints(Foreign key). If exists drop it

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'

BEGIN
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE abcDB.dbo.'+@Table)
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: @M.K.S Welcome. And please accept any one answer if it helps you, that will help people to grow in this community.

Comment: I am new member my reputation does not allow me to accept any question....I have tried it but failed to accept the questions. vote me to increase my reputation

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am eligibled to accept any question

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'
SET @sql='TRUNCATE TABLE abcDB.dbo.' + @Table
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```